# Cross platform application with Qt and Anaconda

Tags: python, qt, anaconda

By Qt I can develop cross platform applications. But If I use Anaconda in my Qt application, will my application still be cross platform?

Anaconda is powered by Python, so it must be dependent upon Python interpreter. Does this dependency on Python interpreter have any effect on being cross platform?

Did anybody develop cross platform applications with Qt and Anaconda? Any points which can be shared?

### Update

I have an application already developed with Qt, QML and C++. I need Anaconda for adding some math-heavy features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anaconda is a **Python distribution**, and it comes with **Conda**, a package manager for various tools and libraries.

Basically Conda manages **environments**, each one containing its own Python and its own set of libraries and tools, on top of the operating system of a Windows, Mac OS
or Linux computer.

So, **it is fine to develop cross platform applications with Qt and Anaconda**: you just need to make sure your dependencies are available for all OSes (go to [Anaconda cloud website](https://anaconda.org) and check before anything else: search for the library/tool you need, and see if it is available for your target platforms).

In case of Qt, we can see version 5.9.7 is available in the default `anaconda`
channel and it is available for those platforms:

- linux-32
- linux-64
- osx-64
- win-32
- win-64

In order to distribute your application, people will need to have Conda installed first. Then, if you make a Conda package of your software, installing it will be as
easy as doing:

```
conda create --name my_env
conda activate my_env
conda install -c my_conda_channel install my_package_name
```

Your code does not need to be written in Python. It is fine to have it written
in C++ for example. It makes things more difficult, though. In this case, you will need to install a compiler to be able to build your software. There are Conda packages for Linux and OSX compilers. For Windows read more [here](https://github.com/conda/conda-build/wiki/Windows-Compilers)

Comment: Very helpful. After reading your post, now I'm researching on feasibility of a plan: (1) Development of my C++ Qt application includes some calls to Miniconda packages (2) Installation of my application (on user's computer) includes running a script which installs Miniconda and sets up packages which are called by my application binaries ... not sure if it is a good plan ...

Comment: The problem I see is compilation of your software. I suggest you to deliver your application within a Conda package, it would make deployment on target computers much easier. On your side it means you need to conda-build your package. Good luck